# Many cases in one request in NSPredicate

Tags: swift, request, nspredicate

I'm using NSPredicate in Swift 3 (in Xcode). I'm trying to force te request to search for multiple words at once. For example: [b,c,t]one would seek for bone, cone and tone. How can I achieve that?

```
let conv = "[b,c,t]one"
let pred = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS[cd] %@", conv)
request.predicate = pred
```

I tried [z,ż,ź]im[n,ń]y for zimny, zimńy, żimny, żimńy and so on. It doesn't seem to work. What's the syntax for that kind of query?

Comment: Have tried replacing `CONTAINS` with `LIKE`?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work too. Is this syntax ([b,c,t]one) correct?

Comment: Contains[cd] with "zim" works, like[cd] with "zim" doesn't work. Both with [z,ż,ź]im don't work. "Zimna woda" is my field, that I'm filtering.

Comment: @BartoszWoźniak: `[cd]` stands for case- and diacritic-insensitive search, so  "name CONTAINS[cd] %@" with "zimny" should match "zimny", "zimńy", "żimny", and "żimńy".

Comment: Ok, now it's working ok. [cd] solved the problem. But what if... I would like to look for every word starting one of e.g. 4 letters. Do I have to create 4 different requests and merge them with "or"? Or can I use something like [b,d,p,l]ump?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "MATCHES" operator with a regular expression pattern.
For example, in

```
let pattern = "[bct]one"
let pred = NSPredicate(format: "name MATCHES %@", pattern)
```

"[bct]" is a [*character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and matches any of the characters "b", "c",
"t", so that the predicate matches the strings "bone", "cone", and "tone".

Comment: That was exactly the answer I was looking for :D